# How to replace div with html onclick using Vue js?

Tags: vue.js

I have a Respond Button inside a div with a Modal attached to it.

```
<div v-if="notification ? notification.type === 'App\\Notifications\\InterviewRequestEmployerReply' : ''">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm text-right" @click="editNotificationRequest(notification)">Respond</button>
</div>
```

If a User clicks the 'Confirm Interview' button, The Respond Button should be replaced with this `<strong class="text-success">Confirmed</strong>`.

I have a method called `createConfirmedInterviewRequest()` that gets called when the User clicks on the 'Confirm Interview' button. So I'd like to create a method that will change the contents and then I would just call that method inside my `createConfirmedInterviewRequest()` method upon Success, but I don't know how to create this method or how this can be done.

Attached is a scrrenshot of my page with the Respond Button and Modal.

How can I do change the contents of the div using Vue?

[image]

UPDATED:

```
data() {
            return {
                notifications: {
                    noti: false
                },
            }
},

computed:{
            computedConfirm(){
                return this.notifications.noti ? true:false;
            }
        },

methods: {
            confirmProcess(){
                this.notifications.noti = true;
            },
}
```

My method:

```
createConfirmedInterviewRequest: async function() {
   this.confirmProcess(`data`);
}
```

Modal with button:

```
<b-button type="submit" variant="success" @click="confirmProcess(`data`)" class="mr-2 mt-2">
   <i class="fas fa-handshake"></i>Confirm Interview
</b-button>
```

Respond button I want to disappear and substitute with `<strong class="text-success">Confirmed</strong>`.

```
<div v-if="notification ? notification.type === 'App\\Notifications\\InterviewRequestEmployerReply' : ''">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm text-right" @click="editNotificationRequest(notification)" v-if="!computedConfirm">Respond</button>
```

Let me know if you need to know what data properties are inside of notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Use `v-if` , `v-else`, condition will change in your `editNotificationRequest` method:

```
<div v-if="notification ? notification.type === 'App\\Notifications\\InterviewRequestEmployerReply' : ''">
    <button v-if="clickConfirmed" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm text-right" @click="editNotificationRequest(notification)">Respond</button>
    <strong v-else class="text-success">Confirmed</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: Do I add clickConfirmed to the ```data()``` or is this supposed to be a method?

Comment: easier to use data property, although it can be computed property over your confirmed value then you dont need change it manually

Comment: My code is using service.js files to make my axios requests, and I'm using ```v-for``` to display all of my data from the database. I'm not sure what you need exactly...

Comment: If you show me an example where you have a method that does anything and then in that method, another method which does what I'm asking. The data can be anything...

Comment: sample implements by data property https://codepen.io/MNSY22/pen/BaoOmGR

Comment: Thank you, but if they leave the page and come back the respondButton appears again. Is there something else we can try? Otherwise I might just have to delete the notification record all together.

Comment: `confirmed` value must be assigned depend on `notification` value, this is the reason i asked jsfiddle of your code, if user confirmed before , so you have `notification` in user data, set `this.confirmed = true` in `mounted` method of your component, i updated Codepen by add this one

Comment: By the way you can use computed property too, ill add it to codepen sample as alternative that you can replace it as `v-if` expression

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not getting it. I reposted my data under UPDATED in my original post. I tried to follow you and added a property called ```noti``` like this:
```
notifications: {
                    noti: false
                },
```
But keep in mind I just added this property to try and follow your code. It does Not mean anything in my application. Please read my post above again under UPDATED if you can still help me, I tried to provide more relevant information.

Comment: `confirmProcess` is your method you named it `createConfirmedInterviewRequest` Updated codepen https://codepen.io/MNSY22/pen/BaoOmGR

Comment: The problem is here: ```@click="createConfirmedInterviewRequest(notifications)"```
I already have an ```@click``` on the button I want to do this on. So I don't think you can have 2 @click on 1 element, which is why I needed to call a function inside a second function...

Comment: why you want call function in another function? merge the codes, you confirmed when received response from server so set `notify = true` there

Comment: because I want the "respond" button to disappear if a button in my app is clicked. The issue is, there is already an ```@click``` method on this button I'm speaking of, because when you click this button a form gets submitted, the Candidate "Confirms the Interview", This creates an event in the db and shows up in the Calendar, I'm using Full Calendar.